# Is the extension of full free group c^* algebra a group?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

It is know that the extension of reduced free group C*-algebra is not a group.(By Haagerup and  Thorbjørnsen). How about the extension of the full group C-*algebra by compact operators?

Comment: Is not a \textit{group}? Or do you mean group $C^*$-algebra. In that case what do you mean? Full? Reduced? Something else? You must be specific here because any separable $C^*$-algebra is generated by some representation of the free group on countably many generators.

Comment: @Owen: I think the OP refers to Ext(A, K(H)) in the sense of BDF et al. In general this is only an abelian semigroup, H and T gave a random matrix proof for the case of A the reduced group Cstar algebra of free groups (but this had already been shown, I forget by whom)

Comment: @Yemon: Ok, yes. This is almost certainly what is meant.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I have just checked the H and T paper again, and in fact they were the first to prove ${\rm Ext}(C^{\ast}_r(F_2))$ is not a group.

Answer (score 4):

Ext  is a group for the full case. Kirchberg proved in Lemma 3.3 of [Commutants of unitaries in UHF algebras and functorial properties of exactness. J. Reine Angew. Math. 452 (1994), 39–77] that the full group C*-algebra of a countable free group has the lifting property.  It is well-known that the extension semigroup of a C*-algebra with the lifting property must be a group (see for example Proposition of  section 4 of Arveson's paper [Notes on extensions of C*-algebras. Duke Math. J. 44 (1977), no. 2, 329–355. ])